# Disable the default Armadillo in C++ when compiled with -fopenmp

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, armadillo

In Armadillo C++, is there any way to disable the default parallelization when compiled with -fopenmp. I would like the parallelization to be on other parts of the code.

The function I'm particularly interested in is eig_sym().

Thanks very much, 
Yantao

Answer (score 3):

Armadillo isn't parallelized with OpenMP, with slight caveats:

- The underlying LAPACK or BLAS implementation may be paralellized.  If you are using OpenBLAS, it is.
- The Armadillo gmm_diag implementation uses OpenMP.

So the simplest way to go is "don't use OpenBLAS, instead use a singlethreaded BLAS".  But that's not the only way to go.

It sounds to me like you want to disable nested parallelism, so that the only parts of the code that are parallelized are at the higher levels of your code and not in `eig_sym()`.  Here's some documentation on `OMP_NESTED`:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html

So you could either set the environment `OMP_NESTED` to false at runtime, or with `omp_set_nested()` in your code.